# how can I get the old battery health charging back?

Tags: laptop, battery, asus-laptop, zenbook, ux

I have a Zenbook UX410UF and used to enjoy the battery health charging in gaming and continuous usages. A few days ago my laptop went through a journey which changed its windows version from Pro to Enterprise and the battery health charging is gone.

I did install the Utilities Version V1.0.5.63 but it didn't bring the setting back.

I would like to know if changing back to the Windows 10 Pro and doing all the drivers reinstalled is what I should do or is there a trick to get it on enterprise too.

Comment: "battery health charging" what is this? more details please.

Comment: it's a well known capability of many zenbook laptops which allows the battery to remain 60% or 80% while in charging. goal is to maximize battery life otherwise you'll have to plug it in when it's around 20% and unplug when it's around 80% to get similar resault.

Comment: Is there an Asus recovery partition? If so back up your data and use that to get it back to original configuration.

Comment: unfortunately I didn't have the heindsight to anticipate that my SSD is going to get wiped via format and a new crappy windows is going to get installed on the HDD and when I took it to a computer specialist he said he can recover almost everything but not the windows itself.
for a steep price for my budget I may add, so I took it a computer shop and asked them to install a "good" windows on the ssd and and delete the crappy windows which they honestly obliged.

Comment: I would update the BIOS as a first troubleshooting step even though I realize that the problem was introduced by an OS update. It sounds like something that the BIOS would be involved in.

Comment: Contact Asus ad see if they offer recovery media for your model.

Answer (score 3):

You can download it [here](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/Apps_for_Win10/ASUS_Battery_Health_Charging/ASUS_Battery_Health_charging_Win10_64_VER100004.zip), just re-install it.